# How to allow navigating radios in a group with arrow keys, and also make them invisible and take up zero space?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, display, linear-gradients

In the snippet below, you can click on options to select them and also use arrow keys to navigate among them.

But there's a space on the left where the invisible radio button is, because it's taking up space.

This space can be removed by setting the `display` of the radios to `none`, but this breaks the arrow key navigation functionality.

How do I get rid of the space without breaking the arrow key navigation?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

input[type=radio] {
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
 }

input[type=radio]:checked~label>div {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="group" id="a">
    <label for="a">
      <div>foo</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="group" id="b">
    <label for="b">
      <div>bar</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="group" id="c">
    <label for="c">
      <div>baz</div>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them as `position: absolute` to remove them from the standard flow of the layout. You can also give them a really high `top` value to render them of the screen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -9999px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~label>div {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="group" id="a">
    <label for="a">
      <div>foo</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="group" id="b">
    <label for="b">
      <div>bar</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="group" id="c">
    <label for="c">
      <div>baz</div>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```